# Mi regex no funciona específicamente en PowerShell

Tags: regex, powershell

He creado una expresión regular para encontrar y contar cadenas específicas en archivos de texto de gran tamaño. La cuestión es que quiero que sólo devuelva aquellos resultados en los que una combinación de dos de los campos NO está repetida.
No soy experto en regex, pero tras varios intentos, he encontrado una expresión que funciona:

`("\d{4,7}",).{0,100},(("Critical")|("High")|("Medium")|("Low")),("\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+")(?![\s\S]*\1[\s\S]*\7)`

En el último bloque de la sentencia, utilizo "lookaheads" negativos, que selecciona los grupos 1 y 7 respectivamente y se asegura de que se descarten los resultados en los que esta combinación de campos ya ha ocurrido. Por ejemplo, en el texto:

```
"123753","ASD-QW12-11034","6.4","Medium","123.456.789.012"
"123753","AWE-CV12-11035","","Low","123.456.789.012"
"123753","ASD-QW12-11123","6.0","High","123.456.789.012"
"123753","MRD-AA12-12345","7.0","Medium","123.456.789.012"
```

Sólo debería devolverse una de las cuatro líneas ya que los campos referenciados se repiten en todas.

He probado esta expresión regular en varios sitios: notepad++, regex101... mi problema es que he creado un script de PowerShell que por algún motivo no funciona de la misma manera y no realiza el descarte, de modo que muestra todo el texto.

```
$input_path = '.\test.txt'
$output_file = '.\extracted.txt'
$regex = '("\d{4,7}",).{0,100},(("Critical")|("High")|("Medium")|("Low")),("\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+")(?![\s\S]*\1[\s\S]*\7)'
select-string -Path $input_path -Pattern $regex -AllMatches  | % { $_.Matches } | % { $_.Value } > $output_file
```

No soy capaz de encontrar ninguna guía que explique cómo se pueden gestionar referencias a grupos específicos en un regex de powershell, o tal vez estoy comentiendo algún error.

Gracias

Comment: Creo que la expresión regular que mencionas no hace lo que quieres. Simplemente te selecciona una línea cuyo primer campo no coincida con el primer campo _de la línea anterior_, pero no de ninguna de las anteriores, como creo que pretendes. Y el campo 7 no tiene relevancia en el resultado. Esto es así en notepad++ y regex101 porque el `\s` del negative-lookahead te "traga" el retorno de carro. Pero no es así en Powershell. En todo caso, la regexp no te sirve. Yo buscaría otra solución sin regexps, pues estas no tienen "memoria" de todas las líneas previas

Comment: No soy experto en Powershell, de modo que no puedo darte otro enfoque para el problema usando este lenguaje. Pero si te sirviera una respuesta en Python, sería bastante sencillo

Comment: @abulafia Aparenteme en el ejemplo que he hecho, la parte del campo 7 no hace nada, pero si incluyo mas lineas en las que varía el primer campo, o el último campo, el de las IPs, o ambos, lo cuenta como un match diferente. En realidad, lo tengo que pasar por textos de miles de líneas con todo tipo de palabras, en este ejemplo uso solo el patrón en el que estoy interesado. Voy a investigar lo que mencionas del retorno de carro, intuyo que el problema puede estar por ahí.

Comment: @Por otro lado te agradezco lo de Python, pero es para usarlo en equipos windows en los que no necesariamente van a tener el python instalado.

Comment: En cualquier caso la solución con tu regex y el look-ahead me parece muy ineficiente. Piensa que tu look-ahead examina _el resto de líneas del fichero_, para asegurarse de que en ninguna de ellas vuelvan a aparecer los campos detectados. Para cada línea del fichero tiene que examinar todas las siguientes. La complejidad de eso es O(n^2), cuando podría ser O(n) si vas examinando sólo cada línea y guardando los campos "ya vistos" para omitirlos cuando se repitan. Claro que esto no se puede hacer con expresiones regulares.

Comment: Además no funciona bien porque el look-ahead no puede comprobar si los campos que aparecen repetidos más adelante lo hacen en la misma línea o en líneas separadas. Mira este contraejemplo---> https://regex101.com/r/S0ZJ1t/2  La primera línea no la detecta, aunque es única, debido a que su primer campo se repite en la línea siguiente, y su último campo se repite dos líneas más abajo.

Answer (score 0):

De la forma que estás usando [`Select-String`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-string?view=powershell-7.1), aplica el regex **línea por línea**, de modo que jamás vas a poder comparar contra el contenido de las siguientes líneas, como estás intentando.

En cambio, para aplicar la expresión sobre el contenido completo del archivo:

```powershell
$arch = Get-Content -Raw $input_path

$arch | Select-String -Pattern $regex -AllMatches | Foreach {$_.Matches} | Foreach {$_.Value}
```